# Invalid IL code IL_0038: newobj in MonoTouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, interop, il

Under MonoTouch the following line of code compiles, but generates an InvalidProgramException:

```
var bytes = new byte[,]{};
```

**System.InvalidProgramException**
`Invalid IL code in Foo: IL_0038: newobj    0x0a000012`

However, the following does not fail at runtime:

```
var bytes = new byte[,]{{}};
```

I am fine with using the second expression. But, is there anything wrong with the first?  If so, shouldn't it fail to compile?

Comment: This looks like a memory corruption but it's hard to tell since the details would be in the (unprovided) parameters / variables used in the unsafe block. Can you provide more details ? including which line throws this exception ?

Comment: Have you tried running PEVerify on the assembly?

Comment: After investigation I found the culprit expression. The debugger would not step into the method with the offending line.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like it's a bug in the C# compiler in MonoTouch, it compiles the expression incorrectly.

If I try with a newer C# compiler (from Mono 2.12), the expression is compiled correctly and the resulting program works.

The current plan is for MonoTouch to start using Mono 2.12 some time later this fall, if it is an blocker for you, you can [open a bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) to see if a fix can make it into an earlier version of MonoTouch.

Comment: This isn't a blocker for me, so I'll wait for nature to take its course.  Thanks for trying it with the new build.